# Computation of a Schwarz Christoffel Mapping with an unbounded image

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have a problem with finding the image of a Schwarz-Christoffel mapping.

> Find the image of $H$ (the upper half-plane) under the map
>
> $$ f(z)=\int_{0}^{z} \frac{d \xi}{\sqrt{\xi(\xi+1)}} $$
>
> where the square root is chosen sich that $f(x)>0$ for $x \in
> \mathbb{R}^+$. Show that $f$ is conformal on $H$.

I know that Schwarz Christoffel mappings map the upper half-plane to a polygon, so I need to determine the vertices and angles. I stared by rewriting the formula as follows

$$
\int_{0}^{z} \frac{d \xi}{\sqrt{\xi(\xi+1)}}
=\int_{0}^{z} (\xi-(-1))^{\frac{1}{2}-1} (\xi-0)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} d \xi
$$

giving me

$$
a_1=-1, a_2=0
$$

for the preimages of the vertices  and

$$
\alpha_1=\frac{1}{2}, \alpha_2=\frac{1}{2}, 
$$

for the angles. Since $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1 \neq 0=n-2$ for $n=2$ I have to introduce $a_3=\infty$ and $\alpha_3=0$. This suggests that the image will be a triangle with one vertex at infinity. Now, in order to see where the three points $a_1,a_2,a_3$ get mapped and to prove that the mappping is biholomorphic (which will imply that the mapping is conformal) I attempted to compute the integral using the substitution $u=\xi+\frac{1}{2}$

$$
\int_{0}^{z} \frac{d \xi}{\sqrt{\xi(\xi+1)}}
=\int_{0}^{z} \frac{d \xi}{\sqrt{\left(\xi^2+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2- \frac{1}{4}}}
=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{z+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d u}{\sqrt{u^2- \frac{1}{4}}}
=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{z+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{4u^2-1}} du
$$

But now I am not sure what to do next. Also, given that I'm still unfamiliar with Schwarz Christoffel mappings I am not sure whether I have made any errors.